# How to execute Tradingview's signals on Binance without a third party site (e.g. Heroku)?

Tags: heroku, pine-script, webhooks

I wrote a trading strategy in Pine (Tradingview), and I am currently using webhook to send signals to a 3rd party site (Heroku) to execute trades on Binance. Ideally I would like Tradingview to execute my trades straightaway on Binance without going through Heroku. How can I do that either directly (Tradingview->Binance) or using an alternative site to Heroku ? My preference is to get rid of the 3rd party site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Automated trades are not supported by Tradingview. You will always need a 3rd party service at the moment.